# IBM Worklight: Unable to add dynamic content windows 8 application

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have made a small demo application in worklight for Android Tablets, IPad and Windows 8 Tablets. I am using vc.openExternalView({},id); method for multiple views. Everything is going smooth in android and IPad native applications but when I run this app in visual studio 2012 for windows 8 base application then after loading first screen an error is occurred

HTML1701: Unable to add dynamic content "some html ...... "

'. A script attempted to inject dynamic content, or elements previously modified dynamically, that might be unsafe. For example, using the innerHTML property to add script or malformed HTML will generate this exception. Use the toStaticHTML method to filter dynamic content, or explicitly create elements and attributes with a method such as createElement.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=247104.

Can somebody suggest the problem!?

Comment: This error is shown in general for Windows8, because they have a different view on security... does this error actually prevents your app from working, or is it just displayed in the Output log?

Comment: My app stuck after getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

You can try wrapping your html injections with Microsoft's API created especially for that

```
        MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction(function(){
            doYourInjectionsHere();
        });
```

Comment: I have tried this solution but no luck. I am using the method like this. Is it right?
MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction(function(){
            loadView("views/welcome.html", "slide", "container");
        });